# mozilla rhino overriding an object method from javascript

Tags: java, javascript, rhino

I'm looking for overriding a java method from javascript in rhino. Here is my code:

```
public class CustomClass {
public String s="some string";
public void doSomething(){}
}
```

and then:

```
        Object wrappedOut = Context.javaToJS(new CustomClass(), scope);
        ScriptableObject.putProperty(scope, "CustomClass", wrappedOut);
        String s="CustomClass.s='aaa'; \n CustomClass.doSomething=function(args){};";
        Object result = cx.evaluateString(scope, s, "<cmd>", 1, null);
```

So it is possible to change the value to CustomClass.s but not to the method doSomething

I receive the following error:

> org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: Java method "doSomething"
>   cannot be assigned to. (#2)

**UPDATE**
As requested in the comments here is my complete source code:

CustomClass.java

```
public class CustomClass {
    public String s="Do something now!";

    public void doSomething(Object ... v){
        System.out.println("do something");
    }
}
```

Scripting.java

```
import org.mozilla.javascript.*;
public class Scripting {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        Context cx = Context.enter();
        try {

            Scriptable scope = cx.initStandardObjects();

            Object wrappedOut = Context.javaToJS(new CustomClass(), scope);
            ScriptableObject.putProperty(scope, "CustomClass", wrappedOut);


            String s="CustomClass.doSomething=function(args){};";

            Object result = cx.evaluateString(scope, s, "<cmd>", 1, null);

            System.err.println(Context.toString(result));
        }catch(WrappedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            // Exit from the context.
            Context.exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you overriding the method? I don't see any inheritance in your code.

Comment: @SushilKumar I want to override the method from javascript. see my evaulation String code: CustomClass.doSomething=function(args){};

Comment: I cannot run that code. pls, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: @linski I've updated the post. see the entire code

Comment: I didn't manage to write it exactly the way you asked (hope that I will soon), but I found an alternative solution for overriding a Java method from JS, see an example [here](http://my.opera.com/sutabi/blog/putting-the-java-into-javascript-with-rhino).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this code runs, Rhino doesn't call the Java `doSomething` method. Instead, it tries to call its *javascript counterpart* (which is missing), and then throws a
`sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EvaluatorException: Java class "CustomClass" has no public instance field or method named "doSomething". (#1)` exception.

Your `CustomClass` is a pure Java class with no JavaScript counterpart. If you replace this line in your source:

```
String s="CustomClass.doSomething=function(args){};";
```

with this line:

```
String s = "CustomClass";
```

and evaluate it as a javasript command, it will output as `CustomClass@15e0be38`. This usually means that it is some("15e0be38") instance of a object of class `CustomClass`.

From apidoc for method [`ScriptableObject.defineClass(Scriptable scope,
                               java.lang.Class clazz)`](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/rhino/apidocs/org/mozilla/javascript/ScriptableObject.html#defineClass%28org.mozilla.javascript.Scriptable,%20java.lang.Class%29):

---

> Defines JavaScript objects from a Java class that implements Scriptable. 
>   
> (...)
>  Next, all methods are scanned for special prefixes that indicate that they have special meaning for defining JavaScript objects. These special prefixes are
>
> jsFunction_ for a JavaScript function
>   jsStaticFunction_ for a JavaScript function that is a property of the constructor
>   jsGet_ for a getter of a JavaScript property
>   jsSet_ for a setter of a JavaScript property
>   jsConstructor for a JavaScript function that is the constructor
>
> If the method's name begins with "jsFunction_", a JavaScript function is created with a name formed from the rest of the Java method name following "jsFunction_". **So a Java method named "jsFunction_foo" will define a JavaScript method "foo".** Calling this JavaScript function will cause the Java method to be called. The parameters of the method must be of number and types as defined by the FunctionObject class. The JavaScript function is then added as a property of the prototype.

---

JavaScript `print` method ((defined in the `org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Global` class)) interfaces to Java `System.out.println` method. When run

```
public class CustomClass {

public static class _CustomClass extends ScriptableObject {

    @Override
    public String getClassName() {
        return "CustomClass";
    }

    public int jsFunction_method() {
        System.out.println("from java method");
        return 2;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Context context = Context.enter();
    Global global = new Global(context);
    try {            
        //ScriptableObject.defineClass(global, CustomClass.class); 
        ScriptableObject.defineClass(global, _CustomClass.class);            
        String script = "myInstance = new CustomClass();myInstance+' ';";
        System.out.println(context.evaluateString(global, script, "", 1, null));
        script = "myInstance.method+' '+myInstance.method()";
        System.out.println(context.evaluateString(global, script, "script", 1, null));
        script = "CustomClass.prototype.method=function(){print('overriden from javascript method');return 3;}";
        context.evaluateString(global, script, "", 1, null);
        script = "myInstance.method+' '+myInstance.method();";
        System.out.println(context.evaluateString(global, script, "script", 1, null));
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    finally {
        Context.exit();
    }
  }
  }
```

it outputs:

```
[object CustomClass]
from java method
function method() {
[native code, arity=0]
}
 2

overriden from javascript method
function () {
    print("overriden from javascript method");
    return 3;
}
 3
```

- note that if this same JS code ran in Chrome it would ran differently - return 2 twice.
- if the outer class had been used (as in the comment) there would have been a generic related compiletime error. This code was written using [Rhino 1.7r2](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/rhino/js/1.7R2).